# Is there a way to make system responsive while NetBeans is unpacking the index for Sonatype repository?

Tags: netbeans, sonatype

All the developers in my team here have the same problem - when NetBeans is unpacking the index for Sonatype Repository the system becomes very, very slow. I hope that there is some parameter somewhere so we can reduce the priority of that process in order to make it "behave"?

UPDATE: Thanks to @sashoalm for reminding me about the disk I/O. I have noticed that the process does lots of disk I/O and that probably makes the system unresponsive.

It has a nasty habit of starting at the worst possible time, so we had to turn it off…

Comment: Is the process trashing the hard-disk? In my experience, heavy hard-disk usage is the only thing that actually can make the OS unresponsive, CPU usage isn't such a problem.

Comment: Yep, I noticed that too, but forgot to mention.

Comment: So you either need to figure out how to make Netbeans NOT trash the harddisk, or you can try buying an SSD :)

Comment: I do have an SSD here... It is not NetBeans I think. It is probably Maven that does this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have found a solution. I am not particularly happy with it, but anything is better than nothing.

Luckily, I use Linux exclusively, so I simply reniced the java process that is taking all the system resources. A simple `renice -p <java PID here> -n 10` did the job, and the whole system is now responsive as before.